# Closing SVG tags, explicit or self closing?

Tags: html, svg

I was validating my code, and got the following error `Tag cannot be self-closing. Use an explicit closing tag.` in IE for my svg path because it's self closing.

**`<path`** `d="m53.911,10.023c-1.46-.898-3.195-1.019-4.699-1.019h-3.439c"` **`/>`**

Now I know meta tags in HTML5 don't require the forward dash `/`, you just close them with **`>`**. Does the same thing apply to svg tags? Like so:

**`<path`** `d="m53.911,10.023c-1.46-.898-3.195-1.019-4.699-1.019h-3.439c"` **`>`**

Or… Using an explicit closing tag? Like so:

**`<path`** `d="m53.911,10.023c-1.46-.898-3.195-1.019-4.699-1.019h-3.439c"` **`>`** **`</path>`**

**What is the correct way of closing a path?**

Comment: How did you validate your code? May be validating tool just don't know about SVG?

Comment: To be clear, /'s have no effect on void elements in HTML. So nothing is going to break if you include them, but really now... it's just silly to do so! Personally, I actively remove them when I see them. Save the precious bandwidth. :D

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Whatever validation you're using is working incorrectly.

The HTML standard says that SVG and MathML elements *“[must either have a start tag and an end tag, or a start tag that is marked as self-closing, in which case they must not have an end tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#foreign-elements)”*. I.e. You can write a path as `<path></path>` or `<path/>` but you can't write it as `<path>`

Comment: You see this in the IE11 dev tools if you have an SVG with self closing tags

Comment: Also in Microsoft Edge `HTML1500`

Answer (score 44):

[The answer by Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24301479/) is great, but links to [a document that is marked](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/Overview.html#abstract) as:

> This document has been discontinued and is only made available for historical purposes.

---

I wanted to find some up-to-date specification on this behavior, and here is what I found:

> A **Self-closing tag** is a special form of *start tag* with a slash immediately before the closing right angle bracket. These indicate that the element is to be closed immediately, and has no content. Where this syntax is permitted and used, the *end tag* must be omitted. In HTML, the use of this syntax is restricted to *void elements* and *foreign elements*. If it is used for other elements, it is treated as a start tag.

Source: [W3C HTML5 Reference Editor's Draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#tags)

> **Start tags** must have the following format:
>
> …
>
> 6. Then, if the element is one of the *void elements*, or if the element is a *foreign element*, then there may be a single U+002F SOLIDUS character (/). This character has no effect on *void elements*, but on *foreign elements* it marks the start tag as self-closing.

Source: [HTML Living Standard from WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags)
and [HTML: The Living Standard - A technical specification for Web developers](https://developers.whatwg.org/syntax.html#start-tags)

> Inline SVG and MathML support
>
> …
>
> The syntax `<foo/>` opens and immediately closes the foo element if it is a MathML or SVG element (i.e. not an HTML element).

Source: [HTML5 Parser at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_Parser)

---

Conclusion: What Robert Longson wrote in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24301479/) is still valid. This warning in IE11 developer tools is wrong. Using the self-closing syntax in HTML5 is valid (but only for *void elements*, such as `<br/>`; or *foreign elements*, which are those from MathML and SVG).