# May an inline SVG rect be self-closing?

Tags: html, svg, inline-svg

I have this inline SVG:

```html
<svg
    width="100"
    height="100"
    viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
</svg>
```

Microsoft Edge prints a warning that the *rect* may not be self-closing.

The error code is HTML1500.

Is it true that a rect may not be self-closing?

Maybe someone can provide some link to a specification.

**Edit**:

My question seems to be a duplicate. I'm sorry.

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948210/how-to-avoid-html1500-tag-cannot-be-self-closing-warning-in-ie-when-using-embedd

Comment: Also duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/q/24299969/1006854

Comment: Yes seems to be a duplicate.