# Can SVG markup in HTML5 omit self-closing tags?

Tags: html, svg

From the question *[Do I need a "/" at the end of an <img> or <br> tag, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149641/do-i-need-a-at-the-end-of-an-img-or-br-tag-etc)* I learned that self-closing tags such as `<br />` and `<img />` are entirely optional in HTML5 and may simply be written as `<br>` and `<img>`.

But is that also true for SVG elements placed inline with HTML5? For example, can the `<circle />` tag be written instead as `<circle>`?

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
    <circle cx="500" cy="500" r="500" />
</svg>
```

If it is allowed, is it generally good or bad practice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing SVG paths, explicit or self closing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299969/closing-svg-paths-explicit-or-self-closing)

Comment: @ManojKumar I guess the answer for that question is an answer to this, but that question is asked more from a stance about a specific DOM validation system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below are some rules I found out in the [W3 SVG and MathML elements in HTML documents documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#svg-mathml)

> - SVG and MathML elements whose start tags have a single "/" character before the closing ">" character are said to be marked as
>     self-closing.
> - SVG and MathML elements must either have a start tag and an end tag, or a start tag that is marked as self-closing, in which case they
>     must not have an end tag.
> - SVG and MathML elements whose start tag is marked as self-closing, can’t have any contents.
> - The contents of an SVG or MathML element whose start tag is not marked as self-closing are any elements, character data, comments, and
>     CDATA sections that it contains, with the restriction that any
>     character data it contains must be normal character data.

**I think the second point enforces `svg` elements to have a explicit closing tag or a self-closing tag.**