# Create svg element from string

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

as I'd like to check wether d3js could do with my wishes, I Need to know how to create an svg-element, from a given string.

My Elements are stored in a database. 
They are Strings, that follow the svg rules, like the following:

```
<desc>
  <Insert x='21' y='21'/>
  <Pins>
    <Pin Id='1' x='21' y='1' direction='up' />
    <Pin Id='2'  x='21' y='41' direction='down' />
  </Pins>
  <Properties>
    <Property Id='20010' x='0' y='21' angle='0'></Property>
  </Properties>
</desc>
<circle class='CDC300' cx='21' cy='21' r='20' fill='none'></circle>
<polyline class='CDC300' points='1 21 21 1 41 21' fill='none' />
<text id='20010' class='CDC400' text-anchor='end' x='-2' y='25' >#{BMK}</text>
```

Before creating a svg-element out of this string, I'd like to add a g-tag (Group) and I Need to add transform='translate( **some value of database** )'.
Ok, the last Thing I hope I could do better with d3.

So how do I begin?
I found tons of examples and tutorials but None of them stored the svg-elements in a databse, Only some coordinates or very simple data to place and style the svg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For modern browsers<sup>*</sup> you can use `html()` for appending the whole string to your `<g>` element.

Here is a basic demo. We first create the `<g>` element, then translate it by the value you want, and finally we use the string from the database:

```js
const string = `<desc>
  <Insert x='21' y='21'></Insert>
  <Pins>
    <Pin Id='1' x='21' y='1' direction='up'/>
    <Pin Id='2'  x='21' y='41' direction='down'/>
  </Pins>
  <Properties>
    <Property Id='20010' x='0' y='21' angle='0'></Property>
  </Properties>
</desc>
<circle class='CDC300' cx='21' cy='21' r='20' fill='blue'></circle>
<polyline class='CDC300' points='1 21 21 1 41 21' fill='red' />
<text id='20010' class='CDC400' text-anchor='end' x='-2' y='25' >#{BMK}</text>`;

const svg = d3.select("svg");

const g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(100,50)");

g.html(string);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Also, for that to work, you have to properly close the elements, like:

```
<Insert x='21' y='21'></Insert>
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Because `html` uses `innerHTML` internally, that won't work on SVG elements in old browsers.

Comment: Ah ok, that's pretty simple.
And g is then an object that I could work with…

thanks so far.

Comment: Gerardo, you wrote I have to close the Elements like

    <Insert x='21' y='21'></Insert>

For svg Elements, isn't it enough to close them like this?

    <line x1='0' y1='0' x2='100' y2='50' /> 

or does d3 have issues with this?

Comment: @Telefisch It should not matter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24301479/5768908. But, in the demo above, there is a difference. The issue has nothing to do with D3, though.

Comment: Hello, I did like supposed above and it works fine but the g-tag is disturbing on several Actions like moving or manipulating simple graphics like lines etc... So is there a way to create svg Elements without a g-tag, from a given string like above?

Comment: @Telefisch please, do not ask questions in the comments section. Post it as a new question, with the relevant details.